# Use joomla api in ajax php

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

When i send ajax to some *.php file i cant use joomla api into it.
How can i use it?
Tried to insert this

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..'));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

But get: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /*siteurl*/libraries/php/adduser.php

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/libraries/php/adduser.php',
    data:,
    success: function(result) { 
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
        console.log(exception);
    }
})
```

Comment: Because there is no file in `/siteurl/libraries/php/adduser.php` double check to make sure it is there, any uppercase letters?

Answer (score 0):

`$mainframe` was the way we invoked the core in mambo if I remember correctly, pardon my memory it must have been 2006. Judging from the `DS` separator, I think you're at best following a guide from Joomla 1.5.

Bootstrapping Joomla is well explained in any of the /cli files:
the simplest is garbagecron, this is the relevant part, simply adjust your paths:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package    Joomla.Cli
 */

const _JEXEC = 1;

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php'))
{
    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

class GarbageCron extends JApplicationCli
{
    public function doExecute()
    {
        // your code here
    }
}

JApplicationCli::getInstance('GarbageCron')->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If use ajax in custom component you can create for example ajax view and custom view format example view.ajax.php and then use jquery ajax using this code:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo JUri::base().'index.php' ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                  'data':data,
                  'option': 'com_custom',
                  'view': 'ajax',
                  'tmpl':'component',
                  'format': 'ajax'                                              
                  },
                beforeSend: function(){

                },
                success: function(data){

                }

            });
```

now you can use all joomla api in view.ajax.php file